# Web Services and improper use of headers

Tags: web-services, rest, http-headers

Currently we're developing a RESTful service that has a requirement to return (echo) the newly created/updated resource entity in certain scenarios and alternatively echo nothing back in others; therefore saving network load.

Two solutions have been presented.

**Query Variable**

```
POST http://service/resource?echo=false
```

**Accept Header**

```
if ( request.has_header( "Accept" ) )
    echo back newly created resource
else
    ignore
```

Is the second scenario improper use of HTTP Headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already surmised, the second usage is an improper use of that header. The principle of a "correct" RESTful interface is one that adheres to HTTP standards. Adhering to the standard means using the grammar of HTTP the way it's prescribed. The second proposal would qualify as as *not* using it as prescribed. Don't take it from me (what do I know), take it [from the HTTP spec itself](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

> The Accept request-header field can be used to specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response. Accept headers can be used to indicate that the request is specifically limited to a small set of desired types

That's it. It's meant to be used for Content Negotiation (AKA Conneg); repurposing it, while possible, is frowned upon